# Installing Cam on Pi

Tags: camera, kernel

I have just bought me Raspeberry Pi Camera and want to install Video4Linux on my Pi.

I have updated my Pi with the latest SW, and I have extended gpu_mem to 128 on my Pi. I am ready to go......

I install v4l library with:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libv4l-dev v4l-utils
```

I want to enable the kernel module with:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

The rsult is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'bcm2835_v4l2': Operation not permitted
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Assuming you are running raspbiN Hve you enabled the camera in either the GUI or via sudo raspi-config?

Comment: Using a terminal window from my MAC, but I have not really enabled the camera yet. What I am trying to do is to Install OpenCV 3.2 Python/C++ on Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: Then try running sudo raspi-config and (assuming a recent version) under interfacing options enable the camerra and reboot

Comment: Espen -- I just realized I was searching `/lib/modules` for `*uv4l*`, which of course wouldn't match.   So there is a `bcm2835-v4l2`.  Sorry.  However, pretty sure it was *not* loaded when I ran the camera with the `uv4l` tool, as I doubled checked `lsmod` that way.   I certainly have never had to load it manually to use UV4L userspace stuff.

Comment: Strange. This is what found: pi@raspberrypi:/lib/modules $ ls -al
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Mar 31 10:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Mar 15 15:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Feb 26  2016 4.1.18+
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Feb 26  2016 4.1.18-v7+
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 15 15:51 4.9.14+
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 15 15:51 4.9.14-v7+
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 27 15:51 4.9.17+
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 27 15:51 4.9.17-v7+
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 31 10:25 4.9.19+
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 31 10:25 4.9.19-v7+